# docker-compose bind mount volume file propagation to host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, volumes

I've read on [this tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/docker-nginx-letsencrypt-easy-secure-reverse-proxy-40165ba3aee2/) that when you create a `docker-compose.yml` file, and bind mount volumes, if you don't create the folder on your host, when running `docker-compose up` the folder will be automatically created and populated with the content of the container's folder.

Here is the quote:

> Then you should volume bind two folders. /etc/nginx is where all your configuration files are stored, and /etc/ssl/private is where your SSL certificates are stored. It is VERY important that your config folder does NOT exist on your host first time you’re starting the container. When you start your container through docker-compose, it will automatically create the folder and populate it with the contents of the container. If you have created an empty config folder on your host, it will mount that, and the folder inside the container will be empty.

But it doesn't seems to work for me.
Here are a few things I've checked.

- My docker is not running as root. I created the docker group on my machine and added my user in it, thus I don't need to run `sudo docker <command>`
- I run an ubuntu server 18 LTS
- It doesn't matter if I try to bind mount the volumes as read-only or not
- When running `docker-compose up` it creates the folders, but they are owned by the root user
- The created folder owned by the root user are empty

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    container_name: reverse_nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - "./html:/usr/share/nginx/html"
      - "./conf:/etc/nginx"
      - "./ssl:/etc/ssl/private"
    restart: unless-stopped
```

And here is what is created:

```
icare@icare:~/nginx
$ ls -lR
.:
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  root  4096 Mar 20 15:46 conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 icare icare  269 Mar 20 15:27 docker-compose.yml
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  root  4096 Mar 20 15:46 html
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  root  4096 Mar 20 15:46 ssl

./conf:
total 0

./html:
total 0

./ssl:
total 0
```

I can't find a solution online and it seems that a person [asked on github](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/issues/360) and it's been solved the hard way (copying files from the container, then bind-mount everything) but I can't help to think that there is another way. Or maybe the tutorial I'm following is outdated or wrong ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure named volumes and bind mounts behave differently this way, and bind mounts don't get filled with content from the image.  I'd avoid relying on this behavior in any case: this only happens the first time you run a container when a volume is initially created, and you need some story to update the volume when the image content changes.

Comment: I understand that it works OK with a volume. What I'm trying to figure out is if the author of the tutorial used maybe an old version of docker and this behavior with bind-mount is not available anymore (thus, I just move on) or if this can still work and I have to fix something on my side ?
Anyway, I totally agree with you not to rely on such behavior, at least for production purpose. In my case, it is only for a POC at home.